# How to handle firefox default page while executing selenium webdriver Java Script

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Here I have attached error screenshot. This will be getting while running any Test  Script into Firefox browser but same code working fine into Chrome browser.
I am using the latest geckodriver and Firefox browser

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Please share your code which have you tried as well..

Answer (score 0):

You can not control the Homepage using Selenium, But what I think is your homepage is causing any obstruction in your script then you can change your Firefox 
homepage by going to -->

```
FireFox--> **options** --> **General** --> set Home page as "**Show a Blank Page**" from dropdown
```

Comment: Actually, you can manage browser Homepage with appropriate `FirefoxProfile` preferences. However, I don't think that this is an issue OP  concern about